# CMake add_custom_command из подключаемого файла

Tags: linux, cmake

**Подскажите, как заставить (или прописать) команду (add_custom_command), выполняться из подключаемого MakeLists.txt файла ?**

У меня есть основной файл CMakeLists.txt, который в свою очередь вызывает другой CMake файл из иной директории следующим способом:

```
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Resource\ files\ Extention ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Resource\ files\ Extention)
```

В вызываемом файле есть команда:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FILENAME_ONLY}.o
                                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${FILEPATH_ONLY}
                                COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} 
                                ARGS -I binary -O elf64-x86-64 -B i386 ${FILENAME_ONLY} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${FILENAME_ONLY}.o )
```

Данная команда, должна формировать объектные файлы из бинарных, однако выполняет она свою функцию лишь если переместить ее в основной CMakeLists.txt файл. Если же она находится в вызываемом файле, то данная команда игнорируется и файлы не формируются.

Как я понял погуглив, команды добавляемые с помощью add_custom_command - должны всегда находиться в основном файле, однако я для своих целей намерен вынести ее в сторонний файл. Подскажите можно ли сделать подобное ?

Comment: скорей всего правило не игнорируется, а сам файл просто не собирается т.к. от него ничего не зависит или эти зависимости указаны неверно... хотелось бы посмотреть, для чего именно потом эти файлы используются — тут есть пара скользких мест... ну и ещё что за проблема X такая ради которой пришлось пойти на такие изощрения? скорей всего тут достаточно будет отделаться макросом или сборкой статической библиотеки...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Так и получилось, в итоге решил собирать библиотеку. Мне просто для тестов одного из проектов понадобилось вшить файлики с исходными для теста данными в программу (что бы извне из не поменять случайно). И я решил автоматизировать данный процесс. Вот, выложил что получилось: https://github.com/AndreyKrivcov/Resource-files-Extension

Answer (score 0):

У вас проблема в этой строке:

```
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Resource\ files\ Extention ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Resource\ files\ Extention)
```

`subdirectory`, как ни странно, должна быть именно субдиректорией! Вы не можете легально включить в `CMakeLists.txt` другой `CMakeLists.txt` если он не находится в одной из субдиректорий. Вообще в таких случаях `cmake` генерит ошибку а-ля:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (add_subdirectory):
  add_subdirectory not given a binary directory but the given source
  directory "/home/levkovitch/Public/tmp/cmake_test/beta" is not a
  subdirectory of "/home/levkovitch/Public/tmp/cmake_test/alpha".  When
  specifying an out-of-tree source a binary directory must be explicitly
  specified.
```

Посмотрите - у вас должна быть аналогичная

Comment: Нет у меня такой ошибки нет, так как я указал ему верную директорию бинарника. т.е. я директорию бинарника вложенной сделал. А есть ли легальные способы добавить CMake файл рядом лежащей директории ?

Comment: @JamesBondCaesar я ужу написал что нет

Comment: @JamesBondCaesar что у вас выдает `cmake` при конфигурации?

Comment: Касательно изначальной проблемы, то я вроде нашел решение - компилирую включаемую библиотеку resouces.a где все файлы ресурсов собираю. Вреде в таком ключе все работает, сейчас разбираюсь с регулярными выражениями в CMake, нужно в строке символы заменить некоторые

Comment: не чего не выдает, работает нормально, лишь кастомная команда не выполняется. Но когда я поручил ему компилить (*.a) файл - все заработало.

Comment: @JamesBondCaesar cmake при конфигурации не может ничего не выдовать - запустите и посмотрите, он всегда пишет что делает

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, задавать несвязанный абсолютный путь в `add_subdirectory` — решение странное и подозрительное, но ошибкой оно само по себе не является... тебе `cmake` явно говорит, что в отличие от OP'а ты не указал второй параметр — путь к каталогу с бинарниками...

Comment: Благодарю Всех за помощь, я уже решил вопрос. Я хотел изначально что бы CMake файл в другой директории выполнял рад действий в том числе кастомную команду, но не собирал не какой проект. Таким способом не получилось выкрутиться, пошел в итоге по нормальному пути и поручил ему собирать библиотеку, после все заработало. А путь столь странный от того что это я тестовый пример запускал, если интересно - то могу ссылку скинуть на пример что делал, но там не чего особого, просто добавлял файлы ресурсов к экзешнику.